# Getting Syntax Error in two controllers, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am getting two syntax errors in two of my controllers, the post and the members.

I tried to see other people ran into this same error, but I couldn't find a solution to my specific problem. I didn't mess with the Post Controller today while I was writing the members controller, model, and views so I am wondering why I am getting an error in that specific controller to begin with?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!
Eric

C:/community/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:75: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

C:/community/app/controllers/members_controller.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :date, :entry)
  end
end
end


class MembersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @member = Member.new
  end

  def create
    @member = Member.new(params[:member])
    if @member.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Indent your code properly and you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an extra `end` in line 75 of `posts_controller.rb`, and lack an `end` in the end of `members_controller.rb`

Comment: +1 for correct answer. I updated his post with proper indentation so the error is extremely obvious now.

Comment: thanks for your hard work...